# Correct Usage of Capital Letters

Tags: nouns, capitalization

Suppose there is a Department of English (note: the name is not *English Department*) at Abc University. I want to know the correct use of capital letters in these sentences:

> 1. The Department of English at Abc University is really old.
> 2. The English Department of Abc University is really old.
> 3. The English department of Abc University is really old.

I know 1. is correct, but I am not sure about 2 and 3. I am also confused about the appropriateness of the usage of *of* in 2 and 3.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Names should be capitalized, so if you refer to the department by its “official” name, *The Department of English*, you should capitalize the first word and all subsequent “non-connecting” words (so not *and*, *or*, *of*, *in*, etc).

However, if you’re just describing the department, in your case, *The English department*, you should capitalize only the names, so *English*, *Abc*, etc.

To answer you question, I believe (1) and (3) are good.

Comment: A quick glance through the first couple of pages of results for ["the english department at" university](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+english+department+at%22+university&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) suggests that most people capitalise *"Department"* in such contexts. But I doubt many if any of those English departments are actually *called* "[The] English Department" - it's nearly always "Department of English".