# Should I capitalize "chemical engineering department"?

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct Usage of Capital Letters](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4795/correct-usage-of-capital-letters)
>   [To capitalize “department” or not](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18236/to-capitalize-department-or-not)

Which of these sentences is correct?

> The chemical engineering department told me that...
>
> The Chemical Engineering department told me that...
>
> The Chemical Engineering Department told me that...

Comment: It depends on context you haven't told us. Is there some entity whose proper name is "Chemical Engineering Department"? Or is there a department whose proper name is "Chemical Engineering"?

Comment: It's the department of a university.  When I called and asked them something, they gave me an answer.  I now need to convey that to someone else.

Answer (score 10):

- If you have a department called "Chemical Engineering Department", use **"Chemical Engineering Department"**.
- If you have a department called "Chemical Engineering", use **"Chemical Engineering department"**.
- If you are talking about a "chemical engineering department" which doesn't have an official name, use **"chemical engineering department"**.